# add a custom save function to react modal footer button to both handle custom save action and trigger a close

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am getting all mixed up at how I might attach a custom function to a prop I passed into a modal called `handleSaveAction` as you can see below. I want to allow whoever calls the component to be able to pass in a custom save function depending on what needs to be saved. On click of the 'Save Button' I want to call the handleSaveAction that is being passed in as well as triggering the modal to close right after, using `closeModal`. How can I do this in a simple way?

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

const UiModal = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return { isOpen: false };
    },

    openModal() {
        this.setState({ isOpen: true });
    },

    closeModal() {
        this.setState({ isOpen: false });
    },

    render() {
        const { openBtnText, header, subHeader, body, footer, footerText, actionBtnText='See More', closeBtnText='Cancel', placement='central-small', handleSaveAction } = this.props;

        return (
          <div>
            <div className="button" onClick={this.openModal}>{ this.props.openBtnText }</div>
            <div>
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="modal-anim" transitionLeaveTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionAppear={true}
            transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
            { this.state.isOpen ? 
            <div className={`ui-modal-${placement}`} key={placement}>
              <div className="ui-modal-header">
                <UiHeader
                  textTitle={'UiModal Header'}
                  rightSideContent={<UiIcon icon='cancel' dimensions={[18, 18]} color='header-gray' onClick={this.closeModal} />}
                />
                </div>
                <div className="ui-modal-body">
                  {body}
                </div>
              <div className="ui-modal-footer">
                <div className="ui-modal-footer-button-group">
                  <div className="ui-modal-footer-button-close" onClick={this.closeModal}>{closeBtnText}</div>
                  <div className="ui-modal-footer-button button" onClick={this.handleSave}>{actionBtnText}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="ui-modal-footer-text">{footerText}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            : null }
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

export default UiModal;
```

Comment: `onClick={(event) => {this.handleSave(event); this.closeModal();}` ?

Comment: thank you! I am getting an error back ```SyntaxError: Unterminated regular expression (80:145)```

Comment: That seems to be a problem caused by some other code.

Comment: when calling the function within <UiModal />: what is the best way to call it using your syntax?

Comment: `handleSaveAction={}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `handleSave` function to your class that gets called before the function passed in. In that function, check if a function was passed and call that before called `this.closeModal()`. Something like:

```
handleSave() {
  if (this.props.handleSaveAction) {
    this.props.handleSaveAction
  }
  this.closeModal();
}
```

Then on the button: `onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)}`.

Also, worth nothing, both `React.createClass()` and `react-addons-css-transition-group` are deprecated, it might be worth updating your version of React and using ES6 classes.

Comment: looks like everytime any button is clicked - (not just the button the handleSave is attached to) this is getting called.

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or codepen I can see that in?"It works on my machine"